# Working with multiple files in C#

Tags: c#, listview, file-io, struct

I am facing special problem. 
I have a button, which when clicked, will cause click event to open file dialog to choose file. Name of this file  (SafeFileName) will be displayed in combo box. Then I read first 9 rows of that file and store them as struct of this type:

```
public struct DCM_INFO 
{
    public string FILE_NAME;  
    public string FILE_PATH;             
    public string VERSION;
    public string NAME;
    public string DATE;             
    public string BOX;
    public string SERIAL_NUM;
    public string SERIES;
    public string POINT;
    public string NOTE;
    public string VARIANT;     
}
```

First two strings are `"SafeFileName"` and `"FileName"`. 
This struct is then displayed in ListView.

And now the thing I want to do:
After I open second file with exact the same button click event, I want to add second "SafeFileName" to combobox and make it visible(displayed on top), then save data from file in DCM_INFO struct with different name than the first one. After this, If i choose different file than actively displayed in combo box, listview will be updated with adequate data from DCM_INFO struct.
I have figured out the part with combo box (display active file) but how to properly switch between listviews ?

Comment: Sorry its a little unclear what you want to do. It is possible to load more than one file into memory.  Maybe structure your question better.

Answer (score 1):

You could overwrite the ToString method in the struct and add the struct directly to the combobox. In the SelectionCheangeCommited Event of the ComboBox you could extract the item (cast it back to the struct) and create the appropriate ListViewItems which are then added to your ListView (after clearing the ListViews Items collection)

```
public struct DCM_INFO
{
    public string FILE_NAME;
    public string FILE_PATH;
    public string VERSION;
    public string NAME;
    public string DATE;
    public string BOX;
    public string SERIAL_NUM;
    public string SERIES;
    public string POINT;
    public string NOTE;
    public string VARIANT;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return FILE_NAME;
    }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.comboBox1.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            DCM_INFO item = (DCM_INFO)this.comboBox1.SelectedItem;

            // Create ListViewItems and add them to ListView
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        DialogResult ret = ofd.ShowDialog();

        if (ret == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {

            DCM_INFO tmp = new DCM_INFO();
            // read file and fill struct
            this.comboBox1.Items.Add(tmp);
        }
    }
}
```